# Linux Mint kernel damage

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, gzip, system-recovery

First off: I am running Linux Mint 18.2 on an External HDD with Gnome 3 as my desktop.

Recently, I was trying to figure out how to compress my OS so I could move it to a different system. So, I ran:

```
sudo gzip -r -1 /
```

Of course not adding the `-k` option, a lot of my files got compressed into `*.gz` files. I was going to use `find` to find them all and decompress them, but that was too complicated for me to understand which options to use and what not.

So, I went through manually and decompressed as many as I could. I believe I got them all. But there was a problem with my kernel.

It ended up compressing some of the files and I couldn't get them decompressed. So, I took what I could get, which was mostly kernel 4.8.0-53-generic, and the parts I didn't have I took from the kernel in a bootable USB stick.

Now, I can get my system to boot to recovery, and that's it. What's more is X11 is having issues which I assume is also causing the issues I am seeing for lightdm.

I tried running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

In an effort to fix what I could but came up empty. I am now out of ideas. What else can I do to attempt to fix my system?

Re-installation is out of the question due to the amount of time I have put into this system, unless there is a way to reinstall and keep my configuration, apps, and files intact and in use.

Many Thanks!

**EDIT** : By issues for lightdm and x11, I mean I have no GUI. Just a command line.

Comment: *"I was trying to figure out how to compress my OS so I could move it to a different system. So, I ran: sudo gzip -r -1 /"*  This makes me cringe.  Did you really think you could compress *all* files and still have an usable system?  I'm afraid you borked your machine for good.

Comment: Unfortunately your system will never be the same. Your best option is a clean install. In the future, if you like experimenting and hacking, you should backup your stuff on Dropbox or something similar. On a positive note, you learn things by breaking things :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're unclear about the actual problem and damage, the best option is reinstalling the operating system.

Diagnosing a full operating system is not that easy and specially when you don't know the actual damage.

So, boot the system with a live disk, backup all your files and reinstall the system..

The issue you're seeing is a `X11` and `lightdm` issue, but it's not actually clear what has gone. Trying to diagnose a broken system is always good, but if you like to save time the best way is reinstallation.

And infuture always keep a backup and be extra careful while typing anything as `root` user.